# html links & hover events over certain locations on an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

So i created a web site a long time ago using a designer alot like frontpage + expression design put together, and since then Ive gotten more into coding, and I'm learning html, CSS, and all that good stuff.. and i have this re-designed header that Ive made here:

> http://prntscr.com/8zct

So what I need to know, is how i can get it so that when a user clicks on one of the links in the header design it will redirect to a page. and also if possible, how to make it so when a user hovers over a link a drop down may appear with other options, ***EDIT: I'd like to be able to add a backround image to the drop down navigation menu***

As me being quite new to this sort of stuff, could anybody help me achieve this?

PS. I'm working in Visual Studio with ASP. but that doesn't change anything about the html and css stuff. just letting you guys know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate based on clicks on certain areas of an image, read about image maps.

To create menus and other active components, read about JavaScript (also recommended: jQuery).

Comment: Thanks so much! Image mapping was a very good push in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can also create divs that are clickable to use as hot spots on an image.  that way you could add a background image to that div if ti's hovered/clicked, whereas image maps does not afford you that opportunity.